# How can I edit a phone number of a user in user pool of `AWS cognito` before the user is authenticated?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I using `AWS cognito` to verify the user's phone number. I have a problem:
When the user enter his details, I send it to AWS.
AWS try to send code to the user's phone number, but if the user enter a wrong number AWS return exception "invalid phone number". So I ask the user to update the number, but when I try to update it in AWS, they return `exception` "**the user is not authenticated**". How can I update the number to the right number after the user just signup and still not confirmed?
This is my code:

```
                    // Create a CognitoUserAttributes object and add user attributes 
                    CognitoUserAttributes userAttributes = new CognitoUserAttributes();
                    // Add the user attributes. Attributes are added as key-value pairs 
                    // Adding user's given name. 
                    // Note that the key is "given_name" which is the OIDC claim for given name 
                    userAttributes.addAttribute("name", userName); 
                    userAttributes.addAttribute("family_name", userFamily); 
                    // Adding user's phone number 
                    userAttributes.addAttribute("phone_number", prepareValidPhoneNumberForAWS(userPhone));

                    SignUpHandler signupCallback = new SignUpHandler() 
                    {
                        int t=0;
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(CognitoUser cognitoUserUser, boolean userConfirmed, CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails) 
                        {
                            // Sign-up was successful

                            // Check if this user (cognitoUser) has to be confirmed
                            if(!userConfirmed) 
                            {
                                t=0;
                                // This user has to be confirmed and a confirmation code was sent to the user
                                // cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails will indicate where the confirmation code was sent
                                // Get the confirmation code from user
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                // The user has already been confirmed
                                t=1;
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Exception exception) 
                        {   
                            // Sign-up failed, check exception for the cause
                            exception.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    };
                    userPool.signUpInBackground(currentUser.getUser_id(),currentUser.getUuid(),userAttributes,null,signupCallback);
```

Comment: because you are creating new CognitoUser object every time

Comment: I did it just at the first time . When I want to update I use the function :

Comment: CognitoUser cognitoUser = userPool.getUser(currentUser.getUser_id()); and then I use updateAttribute method.

Comment: "the user is not autenticated" means you are not using previous session, you have to just maintain the Session.

Comment: Before you make the call, you can actually retrieve the session and see if the object is null or you can check if the access token is valid

Comment: How can I do it? Can you add sample code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121043/discussion-between-toda-and-rah).

Comment: I don't know exactly but there will be something like getToken() or getSessionToken()

Comment: My user object is not null. it maintain the current user.

Comment: Ok , but what I have to do with getToken() or getSessionToken()? If it is not null so what the problem?

Comment: should be same every time, else you are not maintaining the session which is the cause of problem.

Comment: Yes I have the same user

Comment: What is an error "user not confirm" , I can not update attribute until the user is confirmed?

Answer (score 3):

Currently this usecase is not supported by Cognito because customer needs to be signed-in to update the phone number and unconfirmed accounts cannot sign-in.
One option is to let user create a new account with the correct email address. Another option is that end user contacts developer, developer can use [AdminUpdateUserAttributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminUpdateUserAttributes.html) to update the user phone number.